# How to get intermediate request and final request details using selenium watir webdriver on ruby

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, redirect

Am creating the firefox profile as follows:-

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['general.useragent.override'] = agent
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile
```

and then making a request as below:-

```
browser.goto('http://www.google.com');
```

Steps for redirection as follows:-

1. requesting www.google.com then
2. if its india location, requesting www.google.co.in

How to get intermediate request details as well as final request details using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Use this [stdlib](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html#module-OpenURI-label-Example) for redirection information gathering.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am not getting intermediate request. Its fetching body of the response. Have you tried it.